# How to extract text as well as hyperlink text in scrapy?

Tags: csv, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to extract from following html code:

```
<li>
    <a test="test" href="abc.html" id="11">Click Here</a>
    "for further reference"
</li>
```

I'm trying to do with following extract command

```
response.css("article div#section-2 li::text").extract()
```

But it is giving only "for further reference" line
And Expected output is "Click Here for further reference" as a one string.
How to do this?
How to modify this to do the same if following patterns are there:

1. Text Hyperlink Text
2. Hyperlink Text
3. Text Hyperlink

Comment: You could try a xpath selector `response.xpath('//article/div[@id="section-2"]/li//text()').extract()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are at least a couple of ways to do that:

Let's first build a test selector that mimics your response:

```
>>> response = scrapy.Selector(text="""<li>
...     <a test="test" href="abc.html" id="11">Click Here</a>
...     "for further reference"
... </li>""")
```

First option, with a minor change to your CSS selector.
Look at all text descendants, not only text children (notice the space between `li` and `::text` pseudo element):

```
# this is your CSS select,
# which only gives direct children text of your selected LI
>>> response.css("li::text").extract()    
[u'\n    ', u'\n    "for further reference"\n']

# notice the extra space
#                 here
#                   |
#                   v
>>> response.css("li ::text").extract()
[u'\n    ', u'Click Here', u'\n    "for further reference"\n']

# using Python's join() to concatenate and build the full sentence
>>> ''.join(response.css("li ::text").extract())
u'\n    Click Here\n    "for further reference"\n'
```

Another option is to chain your `.css()` call with XPath 1.0 [`string()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-string) or [`normalize-space()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space) inside a subsequent `.xpath()` call:

```
>>> response.css("li").xpath('string()').extract()
[u'\n    Click Here\n    "for further reference"\n']
>>> response.css("li").xpath('normalize-space()').extract()
[u'Click Here "for further reference"']

# calling `.extract_first()` gives you a string directly, not a list of 1 string
>>> response.css("li").xpath('normalize-space()').extract_first()
u'Click Here "for further reference"'
```

Comment: Thanks paul its very helpful. But I have one question, the html page i'm extracting have many lists one below another. like <li>....</li> <li>...</li>, so while joining them all of them are getting concatinated insted of for one particular list content. So how to seperate list contents and make join of the text and hyperlink only in one list item?

Comment: Try this: `for list_item in response.css('li'): print(''.join(list_item.css('::text').extract()))`

Answer (score 0):

I use xpath if that is the case the selector will be:

```
response.xpath('//article/div[@id="section-2"]/li/a/text()').extract()#this will give you text of mentioned hyper link >> "Click Here"
response.xpath('//article/div[@id="section-2"]/li/a/@href').extract()#this will give you link of mentioned hyper link >> "abc.html"
response.xpath('//article/div[@id="section-2"]/li/text()').extract()#this will give you text of li >> "for further reference"
```